# DIV with float right over DIV with float left

Tags: html, css, floating

Hi I have a navigation div, which has a div on the bottom of it. This div has two other divs "DIV 1" and "DIV 2" (see on picture). Now I the navigation is closed on a tablet device, so I would show the second div which contains float: right over the first div which contains float: left, like in the picture. How can I do this? Now the first div is over the second. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of the DIV's in your html code? DIV1 before DIV2.

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic Hi. Yes. The problem is, when the navigation is opened, the order should be DIV 1 on the left side and DIV 2 on the right. But when it's closed, the DIV 2 should be over the DIV 1... If I change it in the code, the order in the opened navigation wouldn't be correct..

Comment: As Slavenjo pointed out, all you have to do is reverse the order of the divs. div 2 would still be to the right, and div 1 would still be to the left even though you have div 2 first and div 1 second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `Flexbox` and media queries just change `order` of second element to `order: -1` , here is [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/848/)

```css
.nav {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.one {
  background: #5B9BD5;
}
.two {
  background: #FF0000;
}
.div {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .nav {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: normal;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .div {
    flex: 0 0 50px;
  }
  .two {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="div one">1</div>
  <div class="div two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It also workes, if you use in the colapsed nav "flex-direction: column-reverse". Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for that purpose.

You can just manipulate your divs at some point to change their style.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #someElement {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, along with media queries to remove the float at 800px:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ws3m9Lx/

CSS:

```
.div1,.div2 { width: 50%; }
.div1 { float: left; }
.div2 { float: right; }

@media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 800px){
    .div1,.div2 { float: none; width: 100%; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div2">DIV2</div>
    <div class="div1">DIV1</div>
</div>
```